# Application that needs to be installed over any existing version, regardless of version number using Wix

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have an installer of an application that needs to be installed over any existing version, regardless of version number.

Can this be done using Wix 3.7? If yes can I know how to do this ?

Comment: Yes. But, what installer technology does each existing version use? (WiX builds Windows Installer packages, as do several other installer development tools. So, if they are all Windows Installer packages, that would be ideal.)

Comment: Thanks Tom. Yes, both are windows installer packages